# Get value from Master Page into class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I ve a masterpage(myMaster) where I ve a variable(lets call is myInteger) I want to access in an external class.

Usually I just do that in my aspx: <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="myMaster.master" %>

And then I can access to it in my code behind doing: Master.myInteger ...

My issue here is I want to access it in another class(where there is no .aspx)

I tried doing
 Master.MasterPageFile = "~/myMaster.master"
 Master.AppRelativeVirtualPath = "myMaster.master"

but then Master.myInteger isnt recognized.

I'm not sure what I want to do is possible... Any idea to get this variable?

Comment: Define the property elsewhere.  What you're trying to do is not best practice.

Answer (score 3):

So you need to reference a `MasterPage`'s property from a class that does not inherit from `Page`?

I would recommend to use a property or constructor to initialize this class with this value. But if you really need it this way, you can try following approach which uses [`HttpContect.Current.Handler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.handler.aspx):

```
// works even in static context
static void foo()
{
    int myInteger = -1;
    var page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
    if(page != null) myInteger = ((myMaster)page.Master).myInteger;
}
```

Note that this is prone to errors and also hard links your class with a `MasterPage`.

Comment: Thanx but I 'm not sure to see how to do it with a property... (I m a beginer with .Net...). Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @blob: Hard to tell since you haven't shown your class. For example from a page: `Foo foo1 = new Foo(); foo1.myInteger = ((myMaster)page.Master).myInteger;` (assuming that your class has a property `myInteger`).

Answer (score 0):

From an external class, try something like this:

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if (page != null)
{
    var value = ((MasterPageName)page.Master).SomeProperty;
}
```

If you don't have access to the master page from the external class, you can use reflection to access a property or method:

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if (page != null)
{
    var value = page.Master.GetType().GetProperty("SomeProperty").GetValue(page.Master, null);
}
```

Comment: Thx but I'm not sure to understand (english isnt my mother tongue :p ). Where should I write <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Themes/Default.master"%> ? And what the virtualPath is suppose to contains?

Comment: In the page directive (at the very top), below the page declaration: `<%@ Page Language="C#" ... %>`